# Wordpress Media Library not showing images

Tags: php, wordpress, image-uploading

Hello I have a wordpress site and I upload images to media library but the images do not display. In wp-content/upload folder there are other folders like 2015/ and then in that folder there are folders with names 02 and 03 and o1.

Why none of my images are showing in the medialibrary. Image gets uploaded on this path like for instance this image was uploaded

http://sketchfam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/sketchfam-background-1.png

but the image never displays ... what could be the quick solution I have also updated my wordpress to latest version but still the same problem.

Thanks people

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the following solutions:

1. Uploads Folder Permission Issues: Check the wordpress uploads folder at: wp-content/uploads/ to see if its permissions is set to 755, if not change it to 755.
2. Theme files conflict : Try to change the theme to the default Wordpress theme, such as Twenty Twelve or Twenty Ten and see if it gets the problem solved.
3. Also see if disabling any plugins also gets it to work